# Remove parameter name from url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have the following url

```
http://localhost/mybb/index.php?url=widgetboard/questions&step=1&id=1
```

which turns into the following url after applying rewrite rule

```
http://localhost/mybb/widgetboard/questions/step/1/id/1
```

Is it possible to remove the 2 words ie "step" and "id" from the url and add .html at the very end of the url

my code is

```
Options -MultiViews

# turn rewriting on
RewriteEngine On

# When using the script within a sub-folder, put this path here, like /mysubfolder/
# If your app is in the root of your web folder, then please delete this line or comment it out
RewriteBase /mybb/

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(step)/([0-9]+)/(id)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(category)/([0-9]+)/(answer)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(step)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **insert this rule just below `RewriteBase /mybb/` line**:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1/$2&step=$3&id=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry for replying late. It worked great. Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your second rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?step=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then if a user clicks this url: `domain.com/3/120` your PHP script will receive `index.php?step=3&id=120`

Comment: I tried but didn't work.Actually I have another param in the url which is "url".